# Using Several frameworks in a solution?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Several frameworks in a solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325878/using-several-frameworks-in-a-solution)

I have a .net solution that contains several projects.
is it ok if i set the framework of a project to 4.0 and the other to 3.5?
please don't reply something like: "why do you want to do that?" i just have a case that requires me to do so....

Comment: It depends on *which* assembly you set to target which version of the framework, and what your dependency tree looks like. I just can't help but think there might be a better way to solve your problem, if you'd just tell us *why* you feel like you need to do this in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this (with some restrictions), but what you *can't* do is run different versions of the framework in the same process.   So a web project targeting 3.5 and a executable targeting 4.0 is fine.   You can also compile assemblies targeting 3.5 and then use them in a 4.0 project, but you should know that they will all run under the same version when actually executed (or fail to load if you use a manifest to explicitly require a certain version).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only scenario is when you use a 3.5 project in a 4.0 project, 
but you cannot use a 4.0 project into a 3.5 project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have all sorts of different framework versions on different projects within a solution, but if you start to link them together so that the output of one is used by another, then you'll need to make sure they're compatible.

As an aside, if you need to build C++/CLI projects for .NET2 with VS2010, then you need to hand-edit the project file.