# Using Several frameworks in a solution?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a .net solution that contains several projects.
is it ok if i set the framework of some projects to 4.0 and the others to 3.5?
please don't reply something like: "why do you want to do that?" i just have a case that requires me to do so....

Comment: Why ***do*** you want to do that?

Comment: Are you the same person that asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325812/using-several-frameworks-in-a-solution

Comment: @Cody Gray... yes i am...my bad...

Answer (score 4):

Why do you... Yes, that is "ok" to do. But your 3.5 projects can not reference the 4.0 projects. References in the opposite direction are fine though.

Answer (score 1):

It is totally fine to do what you are expecting. Just make sure you are not referencing newer version DLLs in older version. For example, you are not allowed to reference a class library project of 4.0 framework to 3.5 framework project.

That's the only thing you have to keep in mind in general.

There may be other considerations too, but that depends on your project type and the way you want to use a project with each other.

So If this answer doesn't provide details about what you want to know, please edit your question with more specific details about project types.